# Google maps - limit panning between longitudes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I"m trying to set limits to the map view so the user won't be able to
pan it cyclic.
(when panning to the right, instead of the map will cycle, I want it
to stop).

is it possible?

Ori